# passing hidden field to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, parameters, hidden-field

I am using json to run a function in code behind of my app. everything works fine except i cannot figure out how to pass hidden field to it here is my jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             $("input[id$='btnP']").click(function (e) {
 var hiddenfield= $("#<%=hidden.UniqueID%>"); //This Does not work!!!!!
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "MyDoc.aspx/BtnOpen",
                     data: "{'message': '" + hidden.val() + "'}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (msg) {
                         if (msg.d == 'Sent') {

                         }
                         else {

                         }
                     }

                 });

                 e.preventDefault();
             });
```

EDIT:::

My hidden field is in gridview as so:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">                      
         <ItemTemplate>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnP"  runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden"  Value='<%# Eval("ID" )%>'  />
           </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a couple of options to take hidden field value:

1) you can set up ClientIDMode attribute of your hidden field to Static

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="yourValue"/>
```

and then you can use the following code:

```
var hiddenField = document.getElementById('hidden');
....
hiddenField.value
```

2) use ClientID property:

```
var hiddenField = $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>");
...
hiddenField.val();
```

read about the difference between ClientID and UniqueID [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/ASP_NET/re-113573_The_difference_between_ID_ClientID_and_UniqueID.aspx)

**UPD.**

If you need to pass some parameter from GridView to a function, you may not use HiddenField:

Just remove "server" tag from your input and add onclick event.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">                      
    <ItemTemplate>
       <input type="submit" value="Send" id="btnP" onclick="BtnOpen('<%# Eval("ID" ) %>');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And than add your function:

```
<script>
    function BtnOpen(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyDoc.aspx/BtnOpen",
            data: "{'message': '" + id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d == 'Sent') {

                }
                else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this but it says unknown entity. the only problem is that my hidden field is inside gridview..

Comment: @Sam1 ok. it's just another question. have updated my answer - you don't need to use hidden field in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var hiddenfield= $("# ...
```

and

```
hidden.val()
```

The variable is not called `hidden`.

Comment: IIRC, the questioner cannot pass a raw object in `data` if `BtnOpen` is an ASP.NET web method. It has to be a string in that case.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  I'm unfamiliar with that.  I have added the syntax for the string form of `data`.

Comment: It cannot be a query string, actually. It has to be a JSON string (`"{'message': '" + hiddenfield.val() + "'}"` indeed). See [this Encosia article](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/) for the gory details.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Very strange, I'll have to remember this one.  I just went ahead and removed that bit

Comment: @JamesMontagne the only issue here is that my hidden field is inside gridview templatefield->itemtemplate

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("input[id$='btnP']").click(function (e) {

             var hiddenfieldValue = $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>").val(); //This works!!!!!

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "MyDoc.aspx/BtnOpen",
                 data: {"message": hiddenfieldValue},
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",

                 ...
             });

             e.preventDefault();
         });
```

Comment: Sorry it should be `hiddenfield`

Comment: `hiddenfield` is already a jquery object so it doesn't need to be re-wrapped.

Comment: the only issue here is that my hidden field is inside gridview templatefield->itemtemplate, so jquery says unknown entity